# new Expo project | Node.js version 13.14.0 is no longer supportes

Tags: node.js, expo

I am just getting started with Expo and trying to create my first project. I installed Node.js **v14.0.0** via `Homebrew`, and installed  `expo-cli` using `npm` by running the following command as mentioned in the Expo quick start guide:

```
# Install the command line tools
npm install --global expo-cli
```

```
# Create a new project
expo init my-project
```

However, I received an error when running the expo init my-project command which looks like this:

```
ERROR: Node.js version 14.0.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:

>=10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Active LTS)

>=12.0.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS)

>=13.0.0 <14.0.0 (Current Release)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to update the nodejs to the latest version.
Updating the nodejs to latest version resolved my error.